# How to toggle audio play() pause() with one button or link?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have an audio file that plays when an anchor tag is clicked. If the anchor tag is clicked again, I want the audio to pause, I just don't know enough about javascript to pull this second half off. I don't want to change the content of the anchor tag they click, I just want the audio file to start and pause whenever they click the tag.

This is what I have so far, which at least makes the sound file playable:

```
<audio id="audio" src="/Demo.mp3"></audio>
<a onClick="document.getElementById('audio').play()">Click here to hear.</a>
```

Comment: onclick="audio.paused?audio.play():audio.pause()"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A Vanilla Javascript way to do what you required.

Note: I've noticed comments on other question with multiple upvotes for a native js approach and saw the OP has no `jquery` tag.

So **`WORKING EXAMPLE`**:

**`SOLN 1`**: (my initial soln using events)

```js
var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
var isPlaying = false;

function togglePlay() {
  isPlaying ? myAudio.pause() : myAudio.play();
};

myAudio.onplaying = function() {
  isPlaying = true;
};
myAudio.onpause = function() {
  isPlaying = false;
};
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" preload="auto">
</audio>
<a onClick="togglePlay()">Click here to hear.</a>
```

**`SOLN 2`**: (using `myAudio.paused` property based on  [dandavi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368778/how-to-toggle-audio-play-pause-with-one-button-or-link/38665865#comment43189469_27368778))

```js
var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");

function togglePlay() {
  return myAudio.paused ? myAudio.play() : myAudio.pause();
};
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" preload="auto">
</audio>
<a onClick="togglePlay()">Click here to hear.</a>
```

Comment: If anybody ever asks why getters and setters matter; this is the prime example of complexity that arises when makeXTrue(), makeXFalse() is chosen over setX(value).

Comment: I don't think the first solution is worth keeping around. Unless there are problems with support for `paused`, keeping tabs on the player in separate state from its own is not only redundant but also asking for desync trouble if there's ever a problem in your code. A single source of truth in the form of `paused` prevents this.

Comment: `const togglePlay = audio => audio[audio.paused ? 'play': 'pause']()`

Answer (score 10):

```
var audioElement= document.getElementById("audio-player");
function togglePlay() {
    if (audioElement.paused) {
        audioElement.play();
    }
    else {
        audioElement.pause();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery to make a toggle for this.

```
<a id="music-button" style="cursor:pointer;">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT3WE.png"></a>
<audio id="playMusic" autoplay>
<source src="sound.mp3">
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#music-button').toggle(
function () {
document.getElementById('playMusic').play();
},
function () {
document.getElementById('playMusic').pause();
}
);
</script>
```

Comment: Could you also give a pure javascript solution? Not everyone searching for this post will want, or have the ability, to use jQuery.

Comment: @Shane might be a bit late, but I've added a vanilla javascript solution.

Answer (score 1):

the myAudio variable has to be inside the function call...It works fine

```js
function togglePlay() {
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  return myAudio.paused ? myAudio.play() : myAudio.pause();
};
```

```html
<audio 
id="myAudio" src="https://clubajax.pythonanywhere.com/media/contact/backgroundM.mp3" preload="auto">
</audio>

<input type="button" value="sound" onclick="togglePlay()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Sample-Audio = document.getElementById("Sample");

function togglePlay() {
  return Sample-Audio.paused ? Sample-Audio.play() : Sample-Audio.pause();
};
```

```html
<audio id="Sample" preload="auto">
  <source src="./sounds/rain.mp4" type="audio/mp4">
  <source src="./sounds/rain.ogg" type="video/ogg"> 
</audio>
<a onClick="togglePlay()">Click here to hear.</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<audio controls autoplay class="bgsound">
  <source src="audio/motivational-day-112790.mp3" type="audio/wav" />
  <source src="audio/motivational-day-112790.mp3" type="audio/wav" />
  <source src="audio/motivational-day-112790.mp3" type="audio/wav" />
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

**Javascript**

```
    var audioClass = document.querySelector(".bgsound");
    document.querySelector(".play-pause").addEventListener("click", 
    function () {
    if (audioClass.paused) {
    audioClass.play();
     } else {
           audioClass.pause();
            }
     });
```