# Toggle audio "start/stop" with click of image

Tags: javascript

Could someone please help me add some simple functionality to this string?

Here is what I use to allow people to click on an image and play an audio file...the song plays until its over and wont stop.  I would like to allow people to click it a second time to stop the song, and reset it back to the beginning:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var element = $('#starspangledbanner');

    var audio = new 
    Audio('http://siteassets.starspangledbanner.mp3');

element.click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    audio.play();
});

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to toggle audio play() pause() with one button or link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368778/how-to-toggle-audio-play-pause-with-one-button-or-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this code. It's very easy and woks fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var element = $('#starspangledbanner'),
    audio = new Audio('http://siteassets.starspangledbanner.mp3');

  element.click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    
    if(audio.paused){
      audio.play();
    }else{
      audio.pause();
      audio.currentTime = 0;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: hmm - doesn't seem to work for me....  i copied the code exactly.  only change I made was to the actual mp3 file location...

Comment: Yeah, I also use another local mp3 file link. But, it works fine in my browser. There may be another bug in your program. Can you provide me your full code including all HTML and JavaScript? Then, I can debug it properly.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for helping.  I am VERY new at this...I use PageCloud produce the websites, coding is not my thing, I am more of a graphics designer.  So, im not really sure how to get you the HTML code...  HOWEVER, here is the website where this page presides.    www.americanflagmusic.com

Comment: Hi Sorry - I had changed it back to original.  I just changed it to your code...can you take another look.  THANK YOU so much.

Comment: wow thank you so much!  I would like to contact you in the future with this type of question - what would be the best way and how to compensate?