# How to toggle audio play/pause with one button

Tags: javascript, html, audio, playback, pause

I never really worked with javascript before, but I tried googling for a solution to how to make a play/pause button for audio - and I found what appears to be a good and simple solution on this site:
[How to toggle audio play() pause() with one button or link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368778/how-to-toggle-audio-play-pause-with-one-button-or-link)
(PS. I don't have reputation poins enough to comment on Iceman's solution and ask him directly what might be wrong - I would have if I could.)

But, when I paste the code snippets into my document, nothing happens (the resulting text isn't clickable).
Could some of you take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong? It's very possible it's something stupid, but I can't see it myself.

Index.html so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Ukendt Navn ...</title>
    <script>
        var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
        var isPlaying = false;

        function togglePlay() {
        if (isPlaying) {
            myAudio.pause()
        } else {
            myAudio.play();
        }
        };
        myAudio.onplaying = function() {
        isPlaying = true;
        };
        myAudio.onpause = function() {
        isPlaying = false;
        };
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #content {
            border: 1px solid blue;
            margin: auto;
            max-width: 20vw;
            margin-top: 30vw;
            color: black;
        }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <audio id="myAudio" src="birds.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
        <a onClick="togglePlay()">Click here to hear.</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My test site: http://wyrdling.com/other/ukendtnavn/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to toggle audio play() pause() with one button or link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368778/how-to-toggle-audio-play-pause-with-one-button-or-link)

Comment: @Nikola Lukic No, not entirely (as already explained in the post above I couldn't comment on the solution in the suggested post - and writing an "answer" to ask a question just didn't seem right either).

Comment: Ok i am sorry - flag removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to call `document.getElementById("myAudio")` before the element is loaded, therefore you can either call it after the page fully loaded, or place the script right before the end of `body` tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Ukendt Navn ...</title>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function(){
            var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
            
            myAudio.onplaying = function() {
              isPlaying = true;
            };
            myAudio.onpause = function() {
              isPlaying = false;
            };
        });
        
        var isPlaying = false;
        
        function togglePlay() {
            if (isPlaying) {
                myAudio.pause()
            } else {
                myAudio.play();
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #content {
            border: 1px solid blue;
            margin: auto;
            max-width: 20vw;
            margin-top: 30vw;
            color: black;
        }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <audio id="myAudio" src="http://wyrdling.com/other/ukendtnavn/birds.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
        <a onClick="togglePlay()">Click here to hear.</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```