# Playing links to audio on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, audio

My web page includes a bunch of links that are generated via php. These are links to mp3 files, and right now when I click on them the sound starts playing in a new tab. How can I add a script so that all links start playing the source sound directly in the same tab when clicked (and stop when re-clicked)? Apologies in advance for a possibly stupid question, but please have mercy as I am very new to all of these things.

```
<a href="url1" target="_blank">value1</a>
<a href="url2" target="_blank">value2</a>
<a href="url3" target="_blank">value3</a>
```

Comment: You'll need to use an `audio` element like the answer below suggests, however there is much more logic required if you want to dynamically switch the `src` of that `audio`. See the duplicate I marked for example code.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll take a look for sure! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using an `audio` tag like the following:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/

Also, the `target="_blank"` attribute will cause the link to open in a new tab.

Good luck on your coding journey!

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't this bring up the audio player controls? I just want the link text, e.g. "value1" to act as a play/stop button.

Comment: It would, but it's better as far as accessibility goes. If you still want to use an a tag then just remove the target="_blank"

Comment: OK I see I might have misformulated the question. I don't want the page to change, removing the `target="_blank"` would load the page where the audio is located. I want to stay on the same page.

Comment: So then you must use an audio tag..

Comment: you can get rid of the controls by removing the "controls" attribute from the audio tag.
then you can make the audio played on click event of the link, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368778/how-to-toggle-audio-play-pause-with-one-button-or-link)