# General function to play/pause all audio links

Tags: javascript, html, web, audio

I have an html with a bunch of audio links. I am trying to make all of my audio links play/pause on click and I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368778/how-to-toggle-audio-play-pause-with-one-button-or-link). This is exactly what I am after, except that I am now stuck modifying this function to apply to all audio links in my code (since I cannot define one function per link). Ideas on how to do this?

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadAudio(source) {
currentSource = source;
audioSource.src = source;
audio.load();
}

var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
var audioSource = document.getElementById('audioSource');
var currentSource;

document.querySelectorAll('.play-audio').forEach(function(link) {
link.addEventListener('click', function() {
var linkSource = this.dataset.audio;

if (currentSource === linkSource) {
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.pause();
  }
} else {
  loadAudio(linkSource);
  audio.play();
}
});
});
</script>

<audio id="audio">
<source id="audioSource" src=""></source>
Your browser does not support the audio format.
</audio>

<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="#" class="play-audio" data-audio="https://...1">Play 1</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="#" class="play-audio" data-audio="https://...2">Play 2</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Add part of your code to see how are you doing it and where to touch the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to play the audio one at a time. You can play them all through the same audio element by changing the source based on what link has been clicked:

```js
function loadAudio(source) {
  currentSource = source;
  audioSource.src = source;
  audio.load();
}

var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
var audioSource = document.getElementById('audioSource');
var currentSource;

document.querySelectorAll('.play-audio').forEach(function(link) {
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var linkSource = this.dataset.audio;

    if (currentSource === linkSource) {
      if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
      } else {
        audio.pause();
      }
    } else {
      loadAudio(linkSource);
      audio.play();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<audio id="audio">
  <source id="audioSource" src=""></source>
  Your browser does not support the audio format.
</audio>

<a href="#" class="play-audio" data-audio="sound1.mp3">Click here to hear 1.</a>
<a href="#" class="play-audio" data-audio="sound2.mp3">Click here to hear 2.</a>
<a href="#" class="play-audio" data-audio="sound3.mp3">Click here to hear 3.</a>
```

Comment: This seems really nice but I can't get it to work. Clicking on my links plays nothing when I add this (and there was sound before that).

Comment: If it matters, the links are URLs so the audio is not stored locally.

Comment: @CHRD Sorry if this a stupid question but have you replace "sound1.mp3" and the others with links to the mp3 files?

Comment: Haha yes I have XD

Comment: @CHRD Any errors in console? It's working for me so I need a bit more info to help you out :)

Comment: I will edit the question with an example of how the code I generate (with php) looks like :)

Comment: I have added an example of the code that I generate.

Comment: @CHRD Move the `script` tags below the `audio` tag and links :)

Comment: Haha OMG. Totally my bad, thanks for having mercy on a noob! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a selector to find and pause/play your player.

Let's say you have 4 `<audio>` tags

```
<div class='audio-container'>
    <audio id="audio1" src="/Demo1.mp3"></audio>
    <a class='audio-play'>Click here to hear 1.</a>
</div>

<div class='audio-container'>
    <audio id="audio2" src="/Demo2.mp3"></audio>
    <a class='audio-play'>Click here to hear 2.</a>
</div>

<div class='audio-container'>
    <audio id="audio3" src="/Demo3.mp3"></audio>
    <a class='audio-play'>Click here to hear 3.</a>
</div>

<div class='audio-container'>
    <audio id="audio4" src="/Demo4.mp3"></audio>
    <a class='audio-play'>Click here to hear 4.</a>
</div>
```

Using JQuery:

```
$(".audio-container .audio-play").off("click").on("click", function() {
    // $(this) -> ref to the currently clicked <a/>
    //get the [0] element of the FIND query, because a TAG selector returns an array of found elements
    var audio = $(this).parent().find("audio")[0];

    var hasNotStarted = audio.paused && audio.currentTime == 0 && !audio.ended;
    var hasEnded = audio.paused && audio.currentTime > 0 && audio.ended;
    var isPaused = audio.paused && audio.currentTime > 0 && !audio.ended;

    if(hasNotStarted || hasEnded || isPaused)
        audio.play()
    else 
        audio.pause();
});
```

Plain JS

```
//in plain JS, you will have to add a click event listener, on each element

var audioElems = document.querySelectorAll(".audio-container .audio-play");

for (var i = 0; i < audioElems.length; i++) {
    audioElems[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var audio = this.parentNode.children[0]

        var hasNotStarted = audio.paused && audio.currentTime == 0 && !audio.ended;
        var hasEnded = audio.paused && audio.currentTime > 0 && audio.ended;
        var isPaused = audio.paused && audio.currentTime > 0 && !audio.ended;

        if(hasNotStarted || hasEnded || isPaused)
            audio.play()
        else 
            audio.pause();
    });
}
```