# is there a way to pause an audio after being played?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an element play/pause a sound when clicked using the audio object methods: `audio.play()` and `audio.pause()`, but I'm  getting this error:

"Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause(). "

Is there an easy way to resolve this without any libraries?

```
document.querySelector(".head-container").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var audio = new Audio('./sounds/kick-bass.mp3');
    audio.play();
    if (!audio.paused) {
        audio.pause();
    }
});
```

UPDATE, the solution was creating the audio object out of the event listener, my bad. also for anyone interested you can use audio.load() instead of  audio.paused() if you are looking to restart the sound.

```
var audio = new Audio('./sounds/sound.mp3');

document.querySelector(".head-container").addEventListener("click", function () {


    if (audio.paused) {

        audio.play();

    }
    else {
        audio.pause()
        /*audio.load(); */
    }
```

Comment: The `play` and `pause` methods are asynchronous. That is, the code after the call to `play` will run *before* the audio will start playing. Consider awaiting the `play` method or not even playing the audio initially.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51226222/1533592

Comment: Is your condition correct? it seems off

Comment: Can you better describe what is the expected behavior?

Comment: How are you supposed to pause if you make a new Audio object every time you click?

Comment: Why would you attempt to play and then immediately pause?  What are you expecting this to do?  Why call `play()` at all?

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza I want to toggle beetwen play and pause when i click an element.

Comment: @Brad I dont want  to pause immediately unless the user clicks again the element.

Comment: @knosmos thank you, I move the object creation out of the event listener and it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some problem with your conditional statement.
Why not you try using

```
...
var audio = new Audio('./sounds/kick-bass.mp3');
if(!audio.paused) {
    audio.pause();
} else {
    audio.play();
}
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work but thank you.